# How to solve this error that is shown on Windbg?

Tags: c#, c++, windbg

I've loaded a .exe and it gave this error:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: "C:\Users\Public\SoundLog\Code\Código Python\SoundLog\dist\SoundLog.exe"
Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
****************************************************************************
* Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *
* Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *
* After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *
****************************************************************************
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00400000 0061c000   image00400000
ModLoad: 771a0000 772dc000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 76e10000 76ee4000   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
ModLoad: 75460000 754aa000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 76550000 76619000   C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 76b30000 76b7e000   C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 77310000 7731a000   C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
ModLoad: 76ef0000 76f8d000   C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
ModLoad: 75650000 756fc000   C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 65ee0000 65f83000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4926_none_508ed732bcbc0e5a\MSVCR90.dll
(c8.704): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=0012fb0c edx=771e64f4 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=7723e60e esp=0012fb28 ebp=0012fb54 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
ntdll!LdrVerifyImageMatchesChecksum+0x633:
7723e60e cc              int     3
0:000> g
```

Then I pressed F5 and while executing the program gave me this error (this one is what I need to solve):

```
ModLoad: 6f980000 6ff11000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
ModLoad: 6f8e0000 6f97b000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_d08a205e442db5b5\MSVCR80.dll
ModLoad: 752f0000 752fb000   C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
ModLoad: 6e670000 6f168000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\8c1770d45c63cf5c462eeb945ef9aa5d\mscorlib.ni.dll
ModLoad: 03d90000 03dac000   SoundLogC++WrapperDLL.dll
ModLoad: 03db0000 03dcc000   SoundLogC++WrapperDLL.dll
ModLoad: 6afa0000 6affb000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll
ModLoad: 04dd0000 04e13000   msvcm90.dll
ModLoad: 04e20000 04e63000   msvcm90.dll
ModLoad: 76aa0000 76b23000   C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
ModLoad: 75280000 752df000   C:\Windows\system32\sxs.dll
ModLoad: 60340000 60348000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\culture.dll
(b78.9c8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(b78.9c8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(b78.9c8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(b78.9c8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(b78.9c8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(b78.9c8): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(b78.9c8): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (first chance)
(b78.9c8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(b78.9c8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(b78.9c8): CLR exception - code e0434f4d (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=0012e2a4 ebx=e0434f4d ecx=00000001 edx=00000000 esi=0012e32c edi=002bada0
eip=75469617 esp=0012e2a4 ebp=0012e2f4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000212
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll - 
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x54:
75469617 c9              leave
```

Can anyone tell me what is this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Symbol search path is: ****** Invalid ****** might be a start.  The big starred box might be the next place to look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first issue is that you do not have a symbol path set.  You can run ".symfix", as suggested in the message, to automatically select a symbol path using Microsoft's public symbol server.  The second is an unhandled exception.  You need to get proper symbols first, and then run "k" to get a stack trace that should give you more insight into what is happening.

Comment: .symfix -> F5 -> run till exception -> k
                    
is this rigth order?

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide the path of the debug symbols. This can be done via the .sympath command.

```
.sympath c:\debugsymbols;srv*c:\debugmsft*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Additional information is at [Use the Microsoft Symbol Server to obtain debug symbol files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503)

Answer (score 1):

The first error message is telling you, that your symbol path is not set up correctly. The second error is an unhandled exception, but since your symbols are not loaded, it is hard to tell what is going on.

If you have internet access while debugging you can use the `.symfix` command to set the symbol path to point to Microsoft's symbol server. That will give you public symbols for Microsoft DLLs. Make sure to do this before you start debugging.

Comment: That should by `.symfix`, as mentioned by others.

Comment: DOH! Too tired atm. Thanks. Fixed.